# Laravel - Public_Path is Returned as Local System Path

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have an odd issue but I believe could be readily changed with a configuration I might not know about.

So if I want to access the path of an attachment I use the following code in my blade:

```
{{ $volunteer->photoID->attachment}}
```

Which returns me this:

```
public/volunteers/tgjW0GOQTzSEjG7F5Wlq0G9mEdGJ7fE7TLxpKRyn.jpg
```

But I am trying to put the image inside of a pdf, and because of the loading requirements, I am having to format the return in the blade as such:

```
{{ public_path($volunteer->photoID->attachment)}}
```

The problem is this returns:

```
E:\webserver\htdocs\hopin\public\public/volunteers/tgjW0GOQTzSEjG7F5Wlq0G9mEdGJ7fE7TLxpKRyn.jpg
```

Which isn't usable in the img element. So is there something I am doing wrong? Or is there a better way of creating the usable path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [realpath](http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php) when outputting the attachment:

```
{{ realpath(public_path($volunteer->photoID->attachment)) }}
```